# How to run a SQL Query for character in Post Titles

Tags: query-posts, database

Pretty much self explanatory.  I have a development server running the latest WP, and I imported a bunch of posts from a blogger account.  After the import, every post was titled as such: **>Example Title** . What i want to do is a run a sql query to delete all the "**>**" characters in the post titles. I've checked other tutorials already, but still do not understand the complete syntax of the query.  Any help is appreciated.

okay this is the query i 'want' to run.
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’); but what I don't understand is that, I'm trying to update my table name (which is by default wp_, right?), and I'm guessing the next step is updating the field name (which is by default wp_posts, right?), and I want to update ALL the Post Titles to remove a character that shows up in front of all of them. Example: >This Is A Post Title . I want to remove the ">" character.  But what I'm lost on is if I'm doing it wrong by naming "wp_" for "TABLE_NAME", and "wp_posts" as the "FIELD_NAME". Or am I missing something in that query just all together?  Hope I'm making it clear and not too confusing.

Comment: Do you have issue with doing this in WordPress or you want to just run query in MySQL (without WP involved)? I am on the fence if this is on topic for us.

Comment: I agree with @Rarst.  Maybe if you included the query you're using, or reference what WP functions (if any) you're trying to use it would help. But as-is, this reads like a straight MySQL question *not* a WordPress question.

Comment: `wp_posts` is the table, as long as you didn't change the table prefix in `wp-config.php` to something other than `wp_`. `post_title` is the field that contains the title.

Comment: @Milo thank you much. but this is what I got

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'â€˜' in 'field list'
UPDATE xxx_posts SET post_title = replace( post_title, ‘ > ’, ‘’ ) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the SQL Query with everything set. This does assume you have the standard wordpress table prefix in your config.

```
update wp_posts set post_title = replace(post_title,">","")
```